# Using Vaadin 8 Add-on with Vaadin 14 Java

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I'm building a web app using Vaadin framework version 14. I would like to use a [layout component add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/circular-progressbar-add-on1/1.1.0/api) that was written for Vaadin 8. I know it's not that easy since they change the approach from basing on the client engine to render everything natively in the browser. But is there a way to add this component anyway? I've searched for any solutions to migrate older components but all I found was just an annotation that they are no longer using old layouts. I have tried using `HtmlContainer` Class to create my own `CustomLayout` as it's says [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/migration/5-components#layouts) but I can only add elements that extend com.vaadin.**flow**.component.Component and not com.vaadin.**ui**.AbstractOrderedLayout. Do you have any ideas how to make it work?

Kind regards,
Marek

Answer (score 4):

You can run a Vaadin 8 or 7 components in Vaadin 14 with [Multiplatform Runtime (MPR)](https://vaadin.com/multiplatform-runtime). That product requires a [Vaadin Prime](https://vaadin.com/pricing) subscription.

I wouldn't recommend that for a new project written in Vaadin 14. Try to find other alternatives written with [Web Components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Components) or Javascript. You can [integrate an existing Web Component into Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/web-components/integrating-a-web-component).

Comment: Here is the product page for MPR if that sounds like an option, but it does seem a bit heavy-weight solution for just a progress bar: https://vaadin.com/multiplatform-runtime

Comment: Is there any other place to search for such alternatives except for the add-on directory search (https://vaadin.com/directory/search)?

Comment: @kupkol You can [integrate an existing Web Component](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/web-components/integrating-a-web-component) into Vaadin.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks for the advice.